# Send file to remote host, execute remote script, get back result

Tags: bash, remote-access

I am wondering if there is any way to create a bash script that accepts 1 parameter, which is file, and then it will do the following

1. automatically log on remote host using sftp (password,username are 
   hardwired somewhere)
2. send a local file over
3. exit and logon to the remote host using ssh
4. execute some scripts
5. get back the result from remote std output.

Comment: Yes this can be done. I can't give you a concrete example right now but I do remember that when I did this I needed to do a manual login to the remote host first to make sure the ssh key was added to the trust store. That info may come in handy...

Comment: 'ssh user@host command' will run command on remote machine. The command can be sh somescript > output.txt. You can then scp the output.txt to your client machine.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem if you use ssh,it is needed to input the password of the remote machine interactively.I know there is a way to set host keys to make it through but that is a little complicated and may not be available in some conditions.

Comment: please edit your question to include these constraints (some ssh keys, and some not). You may be able to pass a password into ssh from you local machine using `expect`, but that will require installing `expect` and taking the time to learn it syntax. Good luck.

Comment: `sshpass` can also be used. However, the password will be visible with `ps` and thus inherently insecure.

Comment: And setting ssh key is not difficult. Use `ssh-keygen` on your client machine. Then append the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your host's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. The permissions of `authorized_keys` file must be 600.

Answer (score 0):

using Perl and [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH):

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
my $sftp = $ssh->sftp;
$sftp->put("/local/path/to/script", "bin/my_script"); # => ~/bin/my_script
$sftp->chmod("bin/my_script", 0755);
$ssh->system({stdout_file => '/tmp/script.out'}, "bin/my_script");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, what I'm looking for is bash solution, mainly because I think(personally) that Net::OpenSSH perl module is hard to install under OS X..